# Partitions into non-negative powers of $2$

Tags: number-theory, generating-functions, integer-partitions

Let $c(n)$ denote the number of partitions of $n$ into non-negative powers of $2.$ (Thus $c(5)=4$ since $5=4+1=2+2+1=2+1+1+1=1+1+1+1+1).$ 
(a). Prove that $1+\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} c(n) q^n=\prod\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} (1-q^{2^n})^{-1}.$
(b). Use part $(a)$ to show that $c(2n+1)=c(2n)$ and $c(2n)=c(2n-1)+c(n).$

I tried to follow the same argument as Apostal(Intro. to Analytic Number Theory) done in his proof in Theorem 14.2. How can I distinguish the coefficient I get by expanding out each series as the one I want ?

Comment: So what happens if you expand $\prod\frac{1}{1-q^{2n}}$? What will the coefficient of $q^n$ be?

Comment: It is generally expected that a problem statement will be accompanied by the poster's thoughts about the problem, also known as "context".  This serves at least two purposes.  On the one hand, it alerts Readers to the level of understanding already possessed by the poster, so that Answers and Comments can be directed at an appropriate level (avoiding in particular the repetition of matters already understood by the poster).  On the other hand it helps direct everyone's attention to what is the real difficulty of an exercise.   Questions that lack an element of triage by the poster get closed.

Comment: It should've been \prod \frac{1}{q^{2^n}}. When expanded I got:
1+q+2q^2+2q^3+4q^4+... , where the coefficients are exactly what I want. How can I make this argument rigorous ? Thank you.